# Passing a String variable or String array into a curl script from python

Tags: python, bash, curl, cron

I have a curl script taken from Vonage's website that send a message to my personal WhatsApp containing whatever is inside the " " after `"text":`

```
curl -X POST https://messages-sandbox.nexmo.com/v0.1/messages \
-u '5bbb*************2mI' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-d '{
"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "1415*********" },
"to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "38*********" },
"message": {
  "content": {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "This message has been sent from Vonage API"
      }
     }
   }'
```

I call the script from curltest.py like so

```
import os 
os.system("bash /home/pi/Desktop/curltest.sh")
```

which is executed by crontable as a cronjob every 30 minutes. This works perfectly, however what I want to do is send values of a String variable or String array instead of typing out the exact message into the `"text":` field, and that String array would be declared and populated in the same python file (if possible).

This is for an undergraduate thesis so it can be as rough as necessary as long as it works.

I already tried declaring a simple variable, removing the " " and putting the variable there, but it gives me a syntax error, same for when I tried to close the ' from `-d '`, put the variable there, and then reopen the ' for the rest of the statement.
We haven't used curl at all so I'm a little out of my depth here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please modify `curltest.sh` as:

```
message="$1"
curl -X POST https://messages-sandbox.nexmo.com/v0.1/messages \
-u '5bbb*************2mI' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-d '{
"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "<Vonage-s number>" },
"to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "<my number>" },
"message": {
  "content": {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "'"$message"'"
    }
  }
}'
```

Then call the script from `curltest.py` with:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["bash", "/home/pi/Desktop/curltest.sh", "put your message here"])
```

Comment: I must apologize for the confusion, when I said 
(`"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "<Vonage's number>" },`)
I didn't mean that there is an actual (`'`) in there, an oversight on my end. 

I meant that it's just where their API number goes. Looks like this:

(`"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "1415*****" },
"to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "38******" },`)

So (`"number": "<Vonage'\''s number>"`) isn't something that I think I need to do. But without doing anything there and just adding the $message I got an InvalidParams Error, "title", failed to read HTTP

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The error may be because I forgot to wrap the $message variable with additional double quotes. I've updated my answer putting extra double quotes around the single quotes. Would you please test it? BR.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you so much for the help. Unfortunately I can't pass a string array (`TypeError: expected str, bit or os.PathLike object`), but it's no problem, I can store each value into it's each own string since I only have a fixed amount of them (5 or 7 can't remember of the top of my head) and then combine them inside of subprocess.call. Once again thank you, marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Good to know now it works. Cheers.

Comment: Can I just ask what the `message="$1"` does, if you don't mind? Looks like a declaration and initialization of a variable, but why `$1`, any specific reason?

Comment: I should bave given explanations of my code. The bash variable `$1` holds the 1st argument passed to the bash script, `"put your message here"` in this case. Am I making myself clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now I understand why when I googled it I saw $1, $2, $3 etc. everywhere, but I couldn't find an explanation. Once again, thanks for everything.

Comment: My pleasure. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to set the message as a bash environment variable inside the python program, and then reference that environment in the bash script. For example, if the python code set the environment variable `CURLY_TEXT` using bash array syntax:

```py
import os 
props=['Hello, world!', '555-1212', '121-5555']
props_str=" ".join(f'"{p}"' for p in props)
os.environ["CURLY_TEXT"] = f"({props_str})"
os.system("bash /home/pi/Desktop/curltest.sh")
```

...then the bash script could reference the array elements like this:

```sh
eval declare -a props="${CURLY_TEXT}"

curl -X POST https://messages-sandbox.nexmo.com/v0.1/messages \
-u '5bbb*************2mI' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-d '{
"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": '\"${props[1]}\"' },
"to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number":  '\"${props[2]}\"' },
"message": {
  "content": {
    "type": "text",
    "text": '\"${props[0]}\"'
      }
     }
   }'
```

**NB:** You'll have to do some tricky things with the single quotes, since the content after `-d`  is surrounded by single quotes: for example to get the bash array variable to substitute, you'll need to end the single-quoted block, add the variable `${props[0]}`, and then resume the single-quoted block.

Comment: If you take a look at my reply to the other answer, you can see you misunderstood the `"from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "<Vonage'"'"'s number>" }`, which I apologize for once again. Considering this I assumed I don't need to change anything about that line and just changed the rest like you suggested and it gave me a `curl: (3) Unmatched close brace/bracket in position 14: world! } } }`

I edited the post to fix my mistake.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a way to pass a Python array and assign to a bash array. I also fixed the quoting error in the `-d` parameter of my original answer.